# Выполнение python-скриптов в MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server

Требуется выполнение скриптов на питоне из под sql server.

Выполнение скриптов делаю через `EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script`. И ряд скриптов выполняются без ошибок и выдают верный результат.

Примеры скриптов, выполняющиеся без ошибок:

1:

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
@language =N'Python',
@script=N'
print(''hello world'')
';
```

2:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'
import pip
import pandas as pd
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
     for i in installed_packages])
df = pd.DataFrame(installed_packages_list)
OutputDataSet = df
'
WITH RESULT SETS (( PackageVersion nvarchar (150) ))
```

Но при этом, выполняя скрипты, где используется внешнее обращение, где происходит поднятие сокета, я получаю ошибку (см. пример ниже). При этом, выполнение этого же скрипта из самого питона ошибок не дает.

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
@language =N'Python',
@script=N'
import sys
import codecs
import requests

tmp = ''7805729430''
headers = {
    ''Content-Type'': ''application/json'',
    ''Accept'': ''application/json'',
    ''Authorization'': ''Token _token_'',
}

data = ''{ "query": '' + tmp  + ''}''

response = requests.post(''url'', headers=headers, data=data)
';
```

Ошибка:

> Сообщение 39004, уровень 16, состояние 20, строка 8 A 'Python' script
>   error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with
>   HRESULT 0x80004004. Сообщение 39019, уровень 16, состояние 2, строка 8
>   An external script error occurred:
>
> Error in execution.  Check the output for more information. Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py",
>   line 141, in _new_conn
>       (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
>   line 83, in create_connection
>       raise err   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
>   line 73, in create_connection
>       sock.connect(sa) OSError: [WinError 10013] Сделана попытка доступа к сокету методом, запрещенным правами доступа

Что делать в такой ситуации? Это проблема с правами?

Comment: Можно предположить, что исходящие соединения по http запрещены брандмауэром.